# Check if second image is subimage of first image

Tags: image, matlab, histogram

I want to find out if a given image is an exact or similar part of another image in matlab.

For example, detecting a score bar in a cricket video frame. I would like to detect if there is a scorebar displayed in the given image or not.

**1. Larger image**

[image]

**2. Another image**

[image]

**3. Check if this is a subimage**

[image]

I want to check if 3 is a part of 1 or not. Not an exact part. For example, even if a scorebar exists in 1, and they are not the same scorebars, that would do.

**What I am trying:**

I am trying to divide the larger image into small parts and take the last part of the image and calculate hue histogram difference with the scorebar image. If it falls below a certain threshold, I should classify that as a part of the bigger image. Is this the right approach or should I follow some other better approach. Please suggest me if you have a better one.

Code I wrote:

```
rgbImage = imread('img7517.jpg'); %bigger image
[r, c, x] = size(rgbImage);
numberOfBins = 256;
r1 = 6*r/7;
im = rgbImage(r1:r,:,1);
subplot(2,2,1);
imshow(im);
hsv = rgb2hsv(im);
h = hsv(:,:,1);
subplot(2,2,2);
hist(h(:), numberOfBins);
[counts, y] = hist(h(:), numberOfBins);
im1 = imread('scorebar.jpg');   %smaller image
subplot(2,2,3);
imshow(im1);
hsv = rgb2hsv(rgbImage);
h = hsv(:,:,1);
subplot(2,2,4);
hist(h(:), numberOfBins);
[count, y] = hist(h(:), numberOfBins);
c = sum(abs(counts(:) - count(:)));
disp(c);
```

## Problem

But this doesn't give me any significance histogram difference between 1,3 and 2,3. Value of `c` for 1,3 is 72949 and for 2,3 is 72875. How do I do this? Is the problem due to code or approach? Please help me solve this problem.

## Edit:

Trying normalized cross-correlation,

```
im1 = rgb2gray(imread('replay.jpg'));
im2 = rgb2gray(imread('scorebar1.jpg'));
c = normxcorr2(im2, im1);
[ypeak, xpeak] = find(c==max(c(:)));
yoffSet = ypeak-size(im1,1);
xoffSet = xpeak-size(im1,2);
hFig = figure;
hAx  = axes;
imshow(im2,'Parent', hAx);
imrect(hAx, [xoffSet, yoffSet, size(im1,2), size(im1,1)]);
```

following [this link](http://www.mathworks.in/help/images/ref/normxcorr2.html). But doesn't gives a similar analysis.

Comment: The way you use hist is ambiguous. I think you might have better results if you specify the location of bins manually.

Comment: @bdecaf Thanks for the suggestion. But you see, I am just 2 days old in matlab, and I could not understand what you are suggesting. Can you explain me in a simpler way. I really know a lot lesser about histograms and images in matlab than it shows in the question. ;) Can you also please check the solution I have added, is there something I can do to improve it?

Comment: In your call you just require `numberOfBins = 256`, but not where they should be - matlab will try to place them clever that the resulting plot looks nice, but separately for each hist command. Meaning in the end the outputs are not comparable. In such a case it's better practice to manually define the bins (see the syntax for hist).

Comment: @bdecaf or the suggestion. I will look this up. And have you seen the solution I am using in the answers? Can I improve that?

Comment: Sorry I haven't used `normxcorr2` so I can't help with that. Could be problematic that the scorebar has very little "features" and it fails because of that.

Answer (score 0):

This class of problem (finding a target image within a larger image) is known as [template matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_matching). Typically you might use [normalised cross-correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation#Normalized_cross-correlation), but there are various different algorithms, depending on your requirements and specific use case.

Unfortunately your home-brew histogram-based algorithm is probably not going to give very good results, as you have already observed, so you'll probably need to try one of the commonly-used methods described in the articles linked to above.

Comment: I have added some more code. I followed a link which I have provided in the question, but I could not get a similar analysis of images as shown in the link. Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

Solution, I got,

```
im1 = rgb2gray(imread('img1.jpg'));
im2 = rgb2gray(imread('scorebar.jpg'));
[r, c, x] = size(rgbImage);
numberOfBins = 256;
r1 = 6*r/7;
im1 = im1(r1:r,:,1);
[counts, y] = imhist(im1, numberOfBins);
[count, y] = imhist(im2, numberOfBins);
c = sum(abs(counts(:) - count(:)));
disp(c);
```

This gives significance hue histogram difference(HHD) between histograms. The images who have scorebars have HHD from 2000-5000, those who don't have scorebars have HHD > 10000.